# Creating an ec2 windows instance with Ami using Aws cli adding ami-roles, tags and EBS

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I am running the following command

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ${Ami_id} --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro --iam-instance-profile Name="bot_syndication_cloudwatch" --key-name my-key\
--security-group-ids sg-27b53b5c,sg-7ddd5306 --subnet-id subnet-96e0d6e0 \
--tag-specifications ResourceType=instance,Tags=[{Key=Name,Value=Stage-Content-Syndication},{Key=Environment,Value=Stage},{Key=Platform,Value=Windows}]\
--block-device-mappings "[{\"DeviceName\":\"/dev/sdj\",\"NoDevice\":\"\"}]" \
```

and I am getting this error

```
sg-7ddd5306, --tag-specifications, ResourceType=instance,Tags=[{Key=Name,Value=Stage-Content-Syndication},{Key=Environment,Value=Stage},{Key=Platform,Value=Windows}]--block-device-mappings, [{"DeviceName":"/dev/sdj","NoDevice":""}], sg-27b53b5c
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with this parameter `--security-group-ids sg-27b53b5c,sg-7ddd5306`

If you have multiple security groups to assign on your ec2 instance, you need to separate with space such as

```
--security-group-ids sg-27b53b5c sg-7ddd5306
```

Comment: Actually there was an Versioning issue . When I use Latest Aws-Cli Version there were all well .

Comment: Thank you . @Frédéric Henri