# AWS ec2 run-instances command to create the instance with multiple security groups in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I'm trying to run in PowerShell the command that creates EC2 instance with 2 security groups "sg-01" and "sg-02":

`aws ec2 run-instances --image-id $amiId --count 1 --instance-type 't3.micro' --key-name $keyPair --subnet-id 'subnet-01' --security-group-ids 'sg-01 sg02'`

But I get the error: `The parameter groupName cannot be used with the parameter subnet`. The problem is with the --security-group-ids parameter which is `'sg-01 sg-02'`. In all [examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html#examples) I can see only one security group used. In this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44910157/creating-an-ec2-windows-instance-with-ami-using-aws-cli-adding-ami-roles-tags-a) it's recommended to separate them with space. I tried the next variants:

`--security-group-ids sg-01,sg02`

`--security-group-ids 'sg-01,sg02'`

`--security-group-ids sg-01 sg02`

`--security-group-ids 'sg-01 sg02'`

But the error is the same. If I try with just one group `--security-group-ids 'sg-01'` then the instance is created successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I was confused by the [run-instances documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html) where the syntax is defined as `"string" "string"...`. The next value helps to create an instance with two security groups:

`--security-group-ids @('sg-01','sg-02')`

Comment: I get `syntax error near unexpected token \`('` with bash

Comment: @Eric, Please not that question is about PowerShell. I didn't investigate the problem for bash but can suppose that you can just separate security groups with space as can be seen in this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69557821/how-do-i-assign-a-new-security-group-to-an-ec2-instance-without-removing-the-cur

Comment: thank you I did not notice it was about `powershell`